# Classic ASP Adding sort function by TD column

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Based on my statement below, how do I sort based on Movie name and date? Basically the user would only clicking the table header, Requirement: I don't want to do in Stored procedure, just a simple click on that  header,is this possible and if Yes how should I go about it?

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
<title>STATUS</title>

<style>
body {
    font: 100% "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
table {
    /* The default setting is border-collapse: separate;. By changing separate to collapse as shown below, the space between each table cell is removed. */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
caption {
    font-size: .9125em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

th,
td {
    font-size: .875em;
    padding: .5em .75em;

}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <% 
'declare the variables 
Dim Connection
Dim ConnString
Dim RS4
Dim SQL4


'define the connection string, specify database driver
ConnString="Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.0.1.21;Database=VISTAT;Uid=sa;Pwd=C@xxxxx1;"

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
SQL4 = "SELECT  top  8  (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112)ORDER BY  filmoccurence desc" 

'create an instance of the ADO connection and RS1 objects
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS4 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

'Open the connection to the database
Connection.Open ConnString

'Open the rs object executing the SQL statement and return records 
RS4.Open SQL4, Connection

'query fire up

If RS4.EOF Then 
Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Dim HTML4, pHTML4
  Dim field14, field15, field16
  Set field14 = RS4("Top8HotFilms")
  Set field15 = RS4("DayOfCount")
  Set field16 = RS4("filmoccurence")

  HTML4 = "<BR><BR><table CellPadding=0 CellSpacing=0 border=1><caption>Top  8 Movies booking for today</caption><TR><TD>Movies</td><TD>Day</td><TD>Occurence</td></TR>"&vbCrLf
   Do While Not RS4.EOF
    pHTML4 = "<TR>"
    pHTML4 = pHTML4 & "<TD> " & field14 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML4 = pHTML4 & "<TD> " & field15 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML4 = pHTML4 & "<TD> " & field16 &  "</TD>"
    pHTML4 = pHTML4 & "</TR>" & vbCrLf
    HTML4 = HTML4 & pHTML4
    RS4.MoveNext
  Loop
  HTML4 = HTML4 & "</table><br><br>" & vbCrLf

  Response.Write HTML4
END IF  'query end


'close the connection and rs objects to free up resources


RS4.Close
Set RS4=nothing

Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this purely in classic asp would be to modify the end of your sql query from `ORDER BY  filmoccurence desc` to `ORDER BY " & Request.Querystring("sortparameter") & " desc`,  and then turn your table column headers into links which can pass the relevant field name to the database query eg

```
<td><a href="thispage.asp?sortparameter=DayOfCount">Day</a></td>
```

There are ways of sorting tables client side with javascript - I'm going to add a javascript tag to the question as I think this might offer a more satisfactory solution, and there are a lot more JS people on SO than Classic ASP users

EDIT

The method above assumes that a querystring value has been passed to the page.  To make it work without one you would need to tweak it a bit - eg

```
dim sortparameter
If  Request.Querystring("sortparameter") = "" Then
sortparameter = "filmoccurence"
Else
sortparameter = Request.Querystring("sortparameter")
End If

SQL4 = "SELECT  top  8  (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112)ORDER BY " & sortparameter & " desc"
```

In a production environment I would very strongly advise that you add range protection to the value of your querystring input, otherwise you would leave yourself open to a SQL injection attack.

As I suggested earlier I think javascript would offer a more satisfactory way of doing what you want to do - it would do it all client side so there would be no need to reload the page every time you wanted to re-order your columns.

Comment: got this errorMicrosoft VBScript compilation error '800a0409'

Unterminated string constant

/stats/stats4today.asp, line 89

SQL4 = "SELECT  top  8  (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) ORDER BY " & Request.Querystring("sortparameter") & " desc

Comment: Do you have a closing quote after `desc`?

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.

Comment: SQL4 = "SELECT  top  8  (OrderTH_strMovieName) as Top8HotFilms,Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) as DayOfCount,count( OrderTH_strMovieName)as filmoccurence FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderTicketHistory] where Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) GROuP  BY OrderTH_strMovieName , Convert(char(8), OrderTH_dtmSessionDateTime, 112) ORDER BY " & Request.Querystring("sortparameter") & " desc"

Comment: above is my latest SQL query after I put closing quote got above error

Comment: Hi JohnThanks :) noted on the parameterised portion